# How to get control on mini window using Teststack.white automation framework?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

I am using Teststack.white automation framework to control UI elements in external apps under WINDOWS platform.
I got the control over main window of application by using these commands

```
// source exe file path.
private const string ExeSourceFile = @"C:\program files\myapp.exe";

//Global Variable to for Application launch
private static TestStack.White.Application Application;

//Global variable to get the Main window of myapp
private static TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window MainWindow;


//start process for the above exe file location
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ExeSourceFile);

// launch the process through white application
Application = TestStack.White.Application.AttachOrLaunch(psi);

//Get the window of myapp  
MainWindow = Application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText("myapp"),
 InitializeOption.NoCache);

//Click the Connect button in main window
TestStack.White.UIItems.Button ConnectButton =
MainWindow.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Button>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Connect"));
ConnectButton.Click();
MainWindow.WaitWhileBusy();
```

Until now, this code opens the application and control the main window and then clicks on CONNECT button. after clicking it opens a new mini window.
I want to have control over that window and want to press OK button on it.
can anyone tell me how do i get that control ?

Comment: Hi I am running into the same problem I was wondering whether you got it fixed or not. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this after opening your mini window

```
var miniWindow = Application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText("miniWindowName"), InitializeOption.WithCache);
Button miniWindowButton = Window.Get<Button>("miniWindowButtonName");
miniWindowButton.Click();
```